# How can I make the server check a site every time? How can I run a script on a server?

Tags: android, server

I'm building an android app which takes product URL as input from user and checks if the price of the product has dropped. It notifies the user with a push notification when the price drops.

I have some code which gets the price of product on Amazon. But, I'm not sure how to proceed from now.

**Acc. to me a server will only host files, so that it is available on the Internet. Am I right??
But I want a server which runs my code - which monitors a page for any changes.**

**How to proceed from now?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "monitor the price on Amazon" then you will have to poll (send periodic requests) to Amazon.

You could have the app do all the work (put the code in retrieve the Amazon page, parse it for price, etc) but this causes problems if/when pages changes, you want to change the polling frequency, etc. It has the advantage that the user's device may not be cut off as a "bot" from Amazon.

You should do this on the server using the web server itself to do the polling, not the app. The server would need to support adding an item to check, notifying the user and then removing an item. That's a lot more complicated than it sounds and Amazon might cut your server off because it is essentially a "bot" - trying to get pricing information without the "shopping experience."

There are a number of web servers that support running server processes in the background to do all of this. You can run something like Tomcat (by Apache) or buy something. If you are not familiar with web servers or something like PHP/JSP then you have a long way to go...

Comment: Thanks @Jim, Having a server do the polling is what I mean too. How can I get more info on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need write a parser for amazon answer. Aand send request to server from time to time.

```
public class TimeService extends Service {
public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 5*60 * 1000; // 5 min
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Timer mTimer = null;

@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if(mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
        } else {
            mTimer = new Timer();
        }
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
    }
class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {
@Override
        public void run() {
            // run on another thread
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
                public void run() {
                    // call request to amazon server
}
});
        }
```

call from activity

```
startService(new Intent(this, TimeService.class));
register in manifest

<application
.... >
.....
```

<service android:name=".TimeService"/>

</application>
}